# How to change HTTP protocol for HTTPS on a MVC2 application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, ssl, https

I have an application developed on MVC2 but I need it to change from HTTP to HTTPS after authentication. How do I manage that and where do I have to put the code?

Thank you,

Ignacio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the filter

```
[UseHttps]
```

to your action method

Comment: to every action method I need to be using HTTPS? Or with doing it only with the authentication method will be enough..?

Comment: You'll probably want to add the filter to every action method that needs to run through HTTPS, or if its every action method in a controller then you could apply the filter at the controller level.

Answer (score 1):

That worked great for me:

http://weblogs.asp.net/jeffwids/archive/2010/08/19/how-to-switch-between-http-and-https-in-asp-net-mvc2.aspx

I added couple of lines to it in order to support ajax requests from shared site master.

http://arturito.net/2011/08/05/how-to-switch-between-http-and-https-in-asp-net-mvc2-and-allow-ajax-requests-from-site-master/